# Connectedness of factors of connected product space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If $A\times B$ is connected, why does it immediately follow that $A$ and $B$ are connected as well?

I know that all functions $A\times B\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ are constant, but how would I prove that all $A\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $ B\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ are also constant?

Comment: Why the downvot please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that all continuous functions on $A \times B$ are constant.

The projection map $\pi : A \times B \to A$ given by $\pi(a,b) = a$ is continouous. So if $f : A \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous, so is $f \circ \pi : A \times B \to \{0,1\}$. So it's constant, and then $f$ is constant as well because $\pi$ is surjective.